# Malformed disk image error on reading gpkg file with Geopandas

Tags: python-3.x, gis, geopandas

I've never worked with GIS data before. I'm learning to do so now. I'm trying to read a gpkg file- ESTAT_Census_2011_V1-0.gpkg file from Eurostat-Grid-Census-2021.zip at (https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/population-distribution-demography/geostat).
I've uploaded this gpkg file to Google Colab and have been trying to read/load it using Geopandas, sqlite3, and fiona.

In all three cases, I get a

> DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed error

when I attempt this in Colab. The size of this file is 1.17GB. Unsure if the size is the culprit.

I was wondering if you could give me some pointers on how to be successful with this. I couldn't understand some of the SO resolutions for malformed disk image errors on SO. Kindly simplify for me.

Link  to the [Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/151mUNJ5wb1_ZwJBVdi1FYqRaHrZ2GFFJ?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a size issue(the file is 1.17GB); probably the case of Google colab not having enough because I attempted the same in a Kaggle notebook and faced no issues.